# How to extract href of a tag in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, xpath

I am trying to scrape this page : https://www.sahibinden.com/kategori-vitrin?date=1day&viewType=Gallery&a5_min=2005&a5_max=2020&category=3530

I need to extract links of ads listed on this page. I provide xpath in yaml file and is then read and interpreted by node.js . In yaml file I simply give it this: `data: "xpath: //html/body/div[4]/div[4]/form/div/div[3]/div[2]"` and in node.js here is how it is interpreted:

```
function getxPath(data, path) {
  try {
    let root = new dom().parseFromString(data);
    
    let results = xpath.select(path, root);
    console.log(results);
    if (results.length > 0) {
      let _results = [];
      for (let r of results) {
        _results.push(r.textContent);
      }
      return _results;
    }
  } catch (exc) {
    console.log(exc);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I want to be able to extract links but so far I get only texts like this:

## 827926997

```
Sahibinden_Temiz_Orj Km_Tramersiz_




                     72.500 TL



                            Yıl:
                        &nbsp;
                        2010


                            KM:
                        &nbsp;
                        108.000


                            Renk:
                        &nbsp;
                        Gri

                    İlan Tarihi:&nbsp;
                    03 Haziran 2020

                    İl / İlçe:&nbsp;
                    İstanbul / Esenyurt
```

How do I get links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to fix your XPath expression. You request `div` element instead of `@href` attribute.

Use the following XPath :

```
//a[@class="classifiedTitle"]/@href
```

Output : 20 links per page.

EDIT : In the `YAML` file, replace double quotes with single quotes, like :

```
data: "xpath://a[@class='classifiedTitle']/@href"
```

Comment: I did it. But since I am reading paths from yaml file it throws this error YAMLException: can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 52, column 57:
     ... @class="classifiedTitle"]/@href"

Comment: Hmm. Did you replace double quotes with single quotes in the expression ? Like : `data: "xpath://a[@class='classifiedTitle']/@href"` ?

Comment: Please edit your answer and make it a part of your aswer